# How can I connect a device to an iPhone app that are both on the same wireless network?

Tags: ios, iphone, connection, wifi, device

I'm trying to learn how to build an app that allows you to connect a device to an iPhone app over WIFI so that I can control the device through my iPhone. I just want to know what line of code I would need to incorporate to the app, in order to perform this task?

Comment: Please, make your question more clear. About what `device` are you talking? Do you have already done app?

Comment: I think it'd be more than one "*line of code*". What have you tried / where have you looked so far?

Comment: @VadymVL just any general hardware/device, it's an educational purpose I do not really have any device in mind. It is a question that I am wondering because I know there are apps that allow you to control your TV through your iPhone.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yes lol but I want to know what sort of function, statement, class, etc. I would have to use. i.e would I use bonjour, NSNetServices CFNetServices, or something else?

Comment: @Jimmy310 This is not so easy as you may think. All depends on the specific device and its hardware and drivers. There are not universal/general library for this purpose. You will need to implement it on your own. And this will require thousand lines of code, not just some "class or function".